# How to achieve the effect of tcolorbox macro package in ConTeXt？

Tags: luatex, metapost, context-lmtx

I am completely new to ConTeXt and have just started to experiment with writing metapost directly within ConTeXt. In Latex , we use the tcolorbox macro package to achieve the effect of code on the left and output on the right, my question is, how can I achieve a similar effect in ConTeXt?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Below I provide something to start with. Working with buffers in ConTeXt is very convenient, so I suggest a macro that simply works with the current buffer. So, in the example below, you define a buffer and then call `MPCodeFig`. The macro consists of one outer frame that uses the `MyBackground` MetaFun (this is very meta!) graphic as a background, and then I ended up with a natural table for the content. There are other ways, and maybe other ways that are more smooth.

A few comments:

- In context you do not need `beginfig` and `endfig`.
- You do not need `btex` and `etex`, just write `"$4$"` and so on.
- I do not know what spacing you wanted inside the boxes, so you might want to play with that.
- Personally, I would prefer a version without the frame with the round corners.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{MyBackground}
  path p, q ;
  p := unitsquare xyscaled (OverlayWidth,OverlayHeight) ;
  fill p withcolor "gray" ;
  p := p enlarged (-1dk,-1dk) ;
  p := p cornered 1dk ;
  q := (p cutafter point 1.5 of p) -- (p cutbefore point 5.5 of p) -- cycle ;
  fill q withcolor "lightgray" ;
  draw p ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[MyBackground][\useMPgraphic{MyBackground}]

\starttexdefinition MPCodeFig
\starttextdisplay
  \startframed
    [width=\textwidth,
     offset=2dk,
     frame=no,
     background=MyBackground,
     foregroundstyle=small]
    \setupTABLE[frame=no,offset=overlay]
    \setupTABLE[c][width=\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2dk-\linewidth\relax]
    \setupTABLE[c][1][align=top]
    \setupTABLE[c][2][align=lohi,loffset=1dk]
    \bTABLE
      \bTR
        \bTD \typebuffer \eTD
        \bTD \processMPbuffer \eTD
      \eTR
    \eTABLE
  \stopframed
\stoptextdisplay
\stoptexdefinition

\starttext

\samplefile{ward}

\startbuffer
z0 = origin ; 
z1 = (4cm,0) ;
z2 = (4cm,3cm) ;

draw z0 -- z1 -- z2 --cycle ;

label.bot("$4$", 1/2[z0,z1]) ;
label.rt ("$3$", 1/2[z1,z2]) ;
label.top("$5$", 1/2[z2,z0]) ;
\stopbuffer

\MPCodeFig

\samplefile{ward}

\stoptext
```

[image: code and fig]

Comment: You should be able to do something like `\define\startMPcodefig{\grabbufferdata[mpcode][startMPcodefig][stopMPcodefig]}` // `\let\stopMPcodefig=\MPCodeFig` to give a nicer interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for your enthusiasm, this is exactly the answer I was looking for